# Unable to login to github from Intellij Community Edition

Tags: github, intellij-idea

I installed Intellij Community Edition (latest version 232.8660.185) on my Chromeos Linux VM. When I try to login to github from Intellij and provide my token, it fails with

> Invalid authentication data. Cannot exchange token: Network is unreachable.

If I try logging in via github instead of the token, and then entering my github username and password in the window that shows up, then it fails saying

> We were unable to authorize you in GitHub. Sorry for inconvenience,
> please try again later.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Could you please share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE and reproducing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Change **HTTP Proxy** setting from IDE.

System Settings >> HTTP Proxy:

**Manual proxy configuration** to **No proxy**.

[image]